# ¿Como evitar que el las fechas superen el periodo actual?

Tags: c#

El siguiente código, lo llamo con un botón que me permite ir al siguiente periodo cada vez que yo le doy clic al botón, se muestra el siguiente periodo, pero no he conseguido que cuando es el mismo periodo deje de avanzar, lo que quiero hacer con este código es indicar que si la fecha de Rango[0] es mayor o igual que la fecha inicial del periodo actual, que se quede ahí, pero no le he logrado

```
private void PeriodoSiguiente()
    {
        Rango[0] = Rango[0].AddDays(7);//aqui le sumo siete dias a la fecha inicial
        Rango[1] = Rango[1].AddDays(7);

        //aqui comparo si la fecha inicial del periodo es igual a la fecha inicial del periodo actual, entonces aqui me deja las fechas del periodo actual
        if (Rango[0] >= Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha[0]))
        {
            //Rango = new[] { Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha[0]).AddDays(-7), Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha[1]).AddDays(-7) };
            Rango[0] = Rango[0].AddDays(-7);
            Rango[1] = Rango[1].AddDays(-7);
        }

        MostrarFechas();// aqui mando a llamar el metodo para mostrar las fechas
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, podes intentar explicarlo de otra manera?

Comment: Define bien tu condición. ¿A qué te refieres con "... cuando la nueva fecha"? ¿A la fecha inicial del rango final o a la fecha final del rango final? ¿Y en "... sea superior a la actual"? Por actual te refieres a la fecha inicial del rango inicial o a la fecha final del rango inicial o a la fecha en la que se ejecuta el método. Explica también a qué se refieren las variables Rango y Fecha, has entendible tu pregunta para quienes estamos dispuestos a ayudarte.

Comment: ya lo modifique

Comment: puedes escribir pseudocodigo o instrucciones(enunciados no codigo) de lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: ¿Debugueando, entra dentro del if?

Comment: si, ya lo comprobe, se supone que al entrar a ese if le resta 7 para que las fechas sean las del periodo actual, pero no nada